# Write raster: Error in .rasterObjectFromFile

Tags: raster, r

I am working on a hydrological model written in R. When I run the following line

```
DEM <- raster("\\D:\\Working\\Research work\\DDD\\Input_ParamFile\\DEM_Gil.tif")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)"
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please provide some relevant background and code to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am working on a hydrological model written in R. When I wants to run my DEM with path [DEM <- raster("\\D:\\Working\\Research work\\DDD\\Input_ParamFile\\DEM_Gil.tif")], the above stated error shows.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include this information rather than wiriting it on a comment? Furthermore, use the `{ }` button to format code properly. It makes it much more readable.

Comment: Are you sure the path provided in the `raster` function exists? Also, what happens if you remove the first two backslashes in the path?

Comment: Perfect. It works by removing first two backlashes. Thanks very much. I am really new in R so made even this very basic mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the error states that the file does not exist. The path you are passing as an argument to the `raster` function should not begin with `\\` as the root is the `D:` disk.

Try removing the first two back slashes so your path looks like this:

`D:\\Working\\Research work\\DDD\\Input_ParamFile\\DEM_Gil.tif`